# Update procs and views in all databases

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm planning for a build which will see each of my user's businesses have their own database i.e. one db per office with each office having about 5 users on average. I want separate databases for many reasons especially portability and backups.

Each db will the exact same structure. There'll be some big procs involved and our business model promises continuous improvement. With that in mind, how can I go about updating the procs and views in each database every time we release a new version or feature?

The technology is PHP and MySQL on Google App Engine. I've read about the mysqldbcopy utility, but i'm wondering if there is a better way or if I should send all my scripts via the php mysqli calls. OR can I somehow run my procs at least from the main database with the client db names as a variable?

I'm lost.

Comment: I wouldn't use multiple databases.. there is no reason to have a standalone database for each office with only 5 users for each.. The backup is not a real reason for this approach. You can do a backup to a single database, which I find more easier. What do you mean by portability?

Comment: By 'portability' I mean easily moved to a hosted environment or copied for training or testing.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

As a general rule, one database is better.  But, there are valid concerns -- particularly around security, backups, and incremental maintenance -- that might suggest multiple databases.  In addition, if any clients want to host the solution themselves, then you have multiple databases.

The typical approach is to make each database self-contained.  It would contain all the stored procedures, functions, tables, triggers and so on that are needed by the application.  That is, there is no "main" database.

If you are thinking of having a "main" database, then you might think about storing all the data there in the first place.

Comment: Agree with all that. So I still need to find a way to update all sbs.

Comment: @Warren . . . You can have a "master" database that contains all your code, including stored procedures to copy the relevant code to other databases.  You would do your development in that database, but the code running for each client would come from their database.

Comment: Hi Gordon - that is possibly my best option. My problem/question is how do I push this code to the other dbs or how I run the code with the client db name as a variable in the master db prices?

Comment: (1) You push the code to other databases by using a stored procedure and scheduling it as a job (or running it manually).  (2) You run this code with the client DB as a variable using dynamic SQL.